# Eclipse SCSS Highlighting doesn't work for "//" comments

Tags: css, eclipse, sass, syntax-highlighting

Eclipse seems to be missing highlighting for `//` comments in SCSS:

[image]

Is there a way I can add that?

I added `*.scss` files to follow the highlighting of *.css files, but the reason why I'm running into this problem is that `//` comments are not allowed in CSS but they are in SCSS.

```
//This line is not properly highlighted
/*This line is properly highlighted*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Eclipse Web Tools Platform CSS editor](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/tjdetags.html) does not support SCSS.

You can use the [**LiClipseText**](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/liclipsetext) plug-in to edit SCSS files.

See [Eclipse Marketplace for plug-ins that support SCSS](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/fileextension_scss).

Comment: LiClipseText does provide better highlighting, but has a lot of drawbacks compared to associating scss with css editor. The usual hotkeys like Ctrl+Shift+C or Ctrl+Shit+F don't work in it, content assist is useless, editor's behavior is unfamiliar (e.g. doesn't autoinsert closing brackets)...